# Random choose a item from an Async Iterator

Tags: python, asynchronous, random, iterator

As the title, I have a AsyncIterator like the code below. I want to choose a random element from it

```py
@classmethod
async def find(cls, bot: Bot, **kwargs) -> AsyncIterable['Participant']:
    """
    Find participants from the database
    :param bot: The bot
    :param kwargs: The kwargs to find
    """
    for data in bot.mongo.giveaways.participants.find(kwargs):
        yield await cls.from_raw_json(bot, data)
```

I tried using `random.sample()` but it only works for normal iterators. How can I do that with AsyncIterators?

Comment: Since you have no way of knowing how “long” the iterator is, you will first need to turn it into a finite list, from which you can then randomly pick an element.